# VS2015 + Cordova Unit Testing Excludes

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I have a VS2015 + `Cordova` + `TypeScript` project that includes unit testing. I have a `tests` folder for all the unit .spec.ts files.

Is it possible to exclude folders (example `./scripts/test`) in the root `/scripts` folder when publishing and still keep the TypeScript intellisense for the excluded folder?
[image]

> Note: I am aware of adding an exclude attribute to the `tsconfig.json`
>   file, but when I do it I loose intellisense in the .spec.ts files in the `./scripts/test` folder.

Ideally, when unit testing, I run a gulp script (`Karma + Jasmine`) that would compile the `./script` TypeScript files and place it into a .karma folder.  When I publish the project for ios, android, windows devices using VS2015 I would like to exclude the unit test file in the app.

It's not a big problem, but I would like to improve my workflow and still rely on VS2015 to publish for mobile devices.

Maybe adding a gulp file `after build` binding to cleanup the `www/script/**/*.spec.js` files would be the solution?

Comment: How is your project configured to compile TS files into `www/script/`? Does your Gulp build define this? If so, any reason you can't change the globs in your script to ignore that test folder when compiling to `www`? Or is the compilation configured by the tools and this `www/script/` folder is automatically being created?

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen I'm using this `tsconfig.json` file [here](https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS-Angular2-beta/blob/master/scripts/tsconfig.json) + VS2015 `F5` key to compile TS files to `www/scripts`.  There is an exception. Right now I'm using gulp to build my `jasmine` `karma` unit testing .js files and to build .js files on `Travis CI`. It works well and I get a `build passing`.  The VS2015 + tsconfig.json controls the compilation for everything else.